# Consolidate multiple callbacks in node.js module exports

Tags: node.js, callback, sails.js

I have a sails.js service which uses restler (rest-client) to make api calls to external apis and fetch data.

The module looks like this:

```
var rest = require('restler');

module.exports = {
    config: {
        url: sails.config.remote_api.base_url.concat('/countries'),
        rejectUnauthorized: sails.config.remote_api.validateSsl,
        options: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    },
    find: function(headers, payload, callback) {
        var request = rest.get(this.config.url, this.config.options);
        sails.log.info('Outgoing Request', { log_id: headers[x - request - id], method: request.method, host: request.host, url: request.url });

        request.on('2XX', function(data, response) {
            callback(data, response);
        });
    }
}
```

In the above code **request.on('2XX',...)** handles the event emitted when response code is in the 200 series.

When we add other handlers for events emitted when response code is in 300, 400, 500 series...this creates a duplication of same callback function for each of the blocks. For e.g.

```
var rest = require('restler');
module.exports = {
    config: {
        url: sails.config.remote_api.base_url.concat('/countries'),
        rejectUnauthorized: sails.config.remote_api.validateSsl,
        options: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    },
    find: function(headers, payload, callback) {
        var request = rest.get(this.config.url, this.config.options);
        sails.log.info('Outgoing Request', { log_id: headers[x - request - id], method: request.method, host: request.host, url: request.url });

        request.on('2XX', function(data, response) {
            callback(data, response);
        });

        request.on('3XX', function(data, response) {
            callback(data, response);
        });

        request.on('4XX', function(data, response) {
            callback(data, response);
        });

        request.on('5XX', function(data, response) {
            data = {};
            data.succeeded = false;
            data.failureCode = 'SYSTEM ERROR';
            data.failureReason = 'A system error has occurred. Please try again. If the problem persists contact support';
            callback(data, response);
        });

        request.on('error', function(data, response) {
            data.succeeded = false;
            data.failureCode = 'SERVICE UNAVAILABLE';
            data.failureReason = 'The service is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.';
            callback(data, response);
        });
    }
}
```

**How do we avoid the duplication of the following lines?**

```
function(data, response) {
    callback(data, response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you really shouldn't. You have been basically handling different event like `2XX`, `3XX` etc. Each event is handled separately and that is a good practice. Anymore simplification could damage the neat design.

Though you can directly use `callback` instead of

```
function(data, response) {
    callback(data, response);
}
```

like this

```
request.on('2XX', callback);
```

Comment: I did upvote but my reputation being low, my upvote has not been displayed.

Comment: On a separate note: If a module.exports has several functions which have repeating code blocks, as per DRY principle how to 1. separate such repeating code into a sub function 2. how to call a subfunction from within module.exports